# Does github build on the server?

Tags: git, github

I see this git repository https://github.com/cbuchner1/CudaMiner
The list of files do not include the EXE file, but when I download the files as zip, the zip file does contain an executable.
My question if the build was done on the server from the source code, or was it uploaded by the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its part of the new releases part of github

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases

So created by the author on the release

Comment: Right, so the binary can be anything else than the source code would produce. Easy way to spread malicious code...

Comment: @user1615362: Yes, but that's no different from pretty much any other open source distribution method. Some people prefer to download binaries, and they bear the risk of running possibly malicious code as a result.